# Listview Android onClick defaul event

Tags: android, listview, onclick

How could I use onClick event from the base ListView in android without using the Adapter. I what to now witch item is selected and in base of that i want to open another layout.

```
 listview.item="Something"
{
setContentView(R.id.layout.Something);
}
```

Please help me. I tried with the simple onClick but it doesn't work.

Comment: You should read the documentation: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Need To create layout XML file

**main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view1" >
    </ListView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

In Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: it didn't work for me, but thank you for the effort :( Do i need to add onClick too? I have only one activity and more layout that work between them,maybe is this the problem?

Comment: listview..setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     
    }
   });

Comment: I have done as you told me i it didn't work. I don't need an adapter...i only need to find out what item is pressed.Beacuse i see that you setOnItemClickListener have as a parametaer an Adapter. Do i need onClick AND  OnItemClick?

Comment: Just use above snippent android manages Adapter.
String str = (String) arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2);
Considering you have string items in listView . You will get proper pressed string from listview

Comment: I love you! You saved my night! I'm sorry for the stupid questions and for bothering you for this stuff, but i'm a nooby in android, i'm use to c# so it's a confustion. Thank you a lot!